# How can I download a file using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, download, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I want to list all the files(from a directory) in the view. When I click anyone of them. Then the corresponding file must be downloaded.
**Note**: I am working in a windows machine.

I have the following code,

### Controller code:

```
$scope.files = [{"name":"aaa.txt", "path":"C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\MyFolder\\aaa.txt"},
                {"name":"bbb.PNG", "path":"C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\MyFolder\\bbb.PNG"},
                {"name":"ccc.xlsx", "path":"C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\MyFolder\\ccc.xlsx"}];
```

### MyFile.tpl.html

```
<div ng-repeat="file in files"> 
     <a target="_self" download="{{file.name}}" href="{{file.path}}">{{file.name}} </a>
</div>
```

But Its not working as expect.

If I use `href="{{file.path}}"` or `ng-href="{{file.path}}"`, `unsafe:` is automatically appended with the href url.

My angular version is 1.2.7, So i tried with adding the following code in my controller

```
angular.module('myModule', [], function ($compileProvider) {

    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file):/);

});
```

Still `unsafe:` exists in the href.

I don't think I can download if I remove `unsafe:`

Since I tried with hard-coded path for eg: `href or ng-href="C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\MyFolder\\bbb.PNG"` but not able to download the file.

**Note:** Its not a matter whether its `\\` or `/`. Both are not working 
Whats wrong with my code. How can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try Using the below code

```
<a download="content.txt" ng-href="{{ url }}">download</a>

<script>
     var content = 'file content';
     var blob = new Blob([ content ], { type : 'text/plain' });
     $scope.url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL( blob );
</script>
```